# How Can I change the button background when is pressed and keep changing after I stop pressing it?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this code, when I press the button the background changes, but when I stop pressing the button, returns to the first background.

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/botonverdeencendido" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/botonverdeapagado"/>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: So you want like change color continuously if button is pressed and stop when stop pressing button?

Comment: Or when user pressed button color changed and when release back to normal, like this?

Comment: You have to change color on button click event rather defining it in style because buttons don't have Active Inactive state they only have Pressed and Released ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add:

android:state_selected="true"

your drawable will be like this:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/botonverdeencendido" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/botonverdeencendido" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/botonverdeapagado" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the background color of button when pressed you can do it like,

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Button pressed color
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            }

            // Button pressed stopped
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I think this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement onClick() function for the particular button

In the layout file,

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click ME!"/>
```

In the activity,

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
```

This will help u I guess.